# Flask AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'

Tags: python, flask-sqlalchemy

Working on a simple web app that should return "Hello, (name pulled from database)."  It's saying that `the object has no attribute for 'name'`  even though name is listed as an attribute in the class.  Can't figure out why it thinks it's not there (unless I'm misunderstanding the error)?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app=Flask(__name__)

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://postgres@localhost:5432/example'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

# initalizes the class/table
class Person(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'persons'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(), nullable=False)

db.create_all()

@app.route('/')
def index():
    person = Person.query.first()
    return 'Hello ' + person.name
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1952, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1821, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 39, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1950, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/lib/python3.8/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1936, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/ZEMEL/Dropbox (Personal)/Code/hello/flask-hello-app.py", line 20, in index
    return 'Hello ' + person.name
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
```

Comment: The error means that `person` is `None`. Your query is not actually fetching anything. Do you have data in the DB?

Comment: Why was django-models added when it clearly isn't Django?

Comment: @PeacefulJames That was it.  Apparently my record had gone into a different table, so this table was empty.  I didn't think to look there because I read the error as a problem with the code, not with the table itself.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

your db either has no content in it or you are fetching the data the wrong way.

```
person=Person.query(name="name").first()
```

should fetch the data with the first person with the name being "name"